# Extract a part of apt repository for offline usage

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, offline

On the office I have a PC with internet access so I can install packages from the online repositories, but I have a PC at home w/o connection and I want to be able to install packages offline. I wonder if there is a way I can grab **a part** of the repository for offline usage and transportable on USB drives so I can move this clone from the office to home, I have tried taking my apt-cache from the office to home but doing dpkg -i does not work at home. Grabbing the hole repository with apt-mirror is not a choice due to reduced storage size at home. What choices do I have???